# Telerik set height cell xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, telerik

How can i set the cell height when i define the TKListView, i used this:

```
var listView = new TKListView();
listView.RegisterClassForCell(new Class(typeof(MyCellView)), "cell");
listView.WeakDataSource = new ListViewDataSource(MyItems);
listView.AllowsCellReorder = true;
listView.Delegate = new MyListViewDelegate(this);

var listContainerView = new UIView();
UIViewStyles.ApplyGroupBox(listContainerView);
listContainerView.AddSubview(listView);
```

is any property to pass in the constructor of the TKListView? i tried something like this:

```
var listView = new TKListView( RowHeight = 100);
```

but did't work

Answer (score 0):

i had to use this:

```
var listView = new TKListView();
var layout = listView.Layout as TKListViewLinearLayout;
layout.ItemSize = new CGSize(View.Bounds.Width, 70);
....
```

Hope it helps somebody in a future